# How to avoid exception driven programming on "connect/disconnect" methods

Tags: exception

I know that exception driven programming is something that shouldn't be done (and I imagine why).
I'm building a library where I have to estabilish a connection with a device, so the programmer will call MyDeviceInstance.Connect on some point and now is where my problem shows up.

I wrote my connect methods as void Connect(), so I'm not returning anything (because actually I don't need anything), but I will throw exception in a lot of situations:

1. If connection already exists
2. If there are some wrong settings in MyDeviceInstance
3. If my interop method deviceConnect will fail (and here is the biggest problem, because it will returns an int that represents **a lot** of errors)

Should *Connect* returns a boolean instead of void?There will be a lot of possibilities that I'll throw an exception.

The second part of this question is on another method, called *void Update()*. This method can works only if MyDeviceInstance is already connected. In this case I'll throw exceptions when:

1. Connection doesn't exist
2. Connection is lost for any reason (and the programmer will not expect this will happen, but can)
3. Other interop errors

Should update returns a bool value instead of throwing all those exceptions (at least, to limit common errors like "connection doesn't exist")?

Thanks for any answer

**EDIT 1:**

I have to be more precise on one point: because we are talking about an **USB** device, when I'll call my method *Update*, this method could fail depending on the device (if is connected or not). More important, if I reconnect the device the interop method will start working again (and the normal method will do the same), without needing a reconnection or things like that (I don't know how this is working internally).

For update methods, should I throw if the device is disconnected? Programmatically speaking this is an exception, but user-speaking this will be a quite-normal situation.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes, a disconnected media device would certainly be an exceptional situation. Your original question was whether or not you should include business rules into exceptions, to which the answer is NO, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on the second question. However I don't think I ever talked about throwing business logic in my application. Can you point me where I'm doing this? (if possible)

Comment: I guess I misunderstood when you explained what errors you would be looking for. I sort of read it as you would be data validating using exceptions instead of handling them with the user. I thought the scope of your error trapping was broader than simply checking the connect/disconnect operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code which calls a method will be prepared to deal with unusual results, the method should indicate unusual results via some means other than exceptions.  If the calling code will not be prepared to deal with unusual results, then such results should cause exceptions.  Unfortunately, there's no way for a class to magically know whether the caller is going to expect unusual results unless the caller tells it somehow.  A common pattern in .net is for a class to provide pairs of "DoSomething" and "TryDoSomething" methods:

```
ResultType DoSomething();
Boolean TryDoSomething(ref ResultType result);
```

Frankly, I think the latter formulation would be better expressed as:

```
ResultType TryDoSomething(ref Boolean ok);
```

or perhaps:

```
ResultType TryDoSomething(ref Exception ex);
```

where "ex", if non-null, would indicate that an exception (ex) would have been thrown by DoSomething (but with a blank stack trace, since the exception won't actually have been thrown).  Another pattern in some cases may be:

```
ResultType TryDoSomething(Action failureAction);
```

If an unexpected situation arises, the code will call the indicated delegate, with a parameter providing details of the context where the situation arose.  That delegate may be able to allow for better error handling and recovery than would otherwise be possible, since it could be called before TryDoSomething gave up on whatever it was doing.  For example, it could direct TryDoSomething() to keep retrying the operation unless or until the object supplying the delegate receives a cancel request.

Answer (score 2):

Use exceptions for exceptional circumstances. So how do you know that you have an exceptional circumstance? It does depend on context of course and there are no hard and fast rules about it. Note that exceptions are heavy-weight, and you should not be using them for normal flow in your application.

In the instances that you mention, most seem to warrant exceptions.

For `Connect`, a connection already existing may not be an exceptional situation. You may want to make it idempotent if you want. Interop `deviceConnect` failing is definitely an exceptional situation. Something you did not expect. You can raise exceptions here, probably mapping the exit codes to meaningful exceptions.

For `Update`, connection doesn't exist is probably an exceptional circumstance and you can raise an exception. Also, connection lost is exceptional. Like this you can evaluate your situations.

Also, you can look at returning an int that is actually the error, rather than a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are exactly the right thing to use in this situation.

1. Exceptions indicate something exceptional happened. In general you expect the connection to succeed so a failure to connect indicates an exceptional event.
2. Exceptions can provide *rich* information about *why* the call failed.
3. You can't ignore an exception (well you have to be deliberate about it). When the action requested represents an invalid request, it's easy for the calling method to just ignore it and continue abusing the connection. An exception forces the caller to deal with the problem.

The primary argument against using exceptions generally revolves performance. Which can be an issue if you're using exceptions for all error passing. However, when the action you are performing should typically succeed, an exception will not have any affect on performance.

Comment: This is true, but the statement was that he is throwing all kinds of exceptions states. I think trapping those expected "exceptions" is the better choice here. But, if they are truly exceptions, like division by 0 rather than the date is out of acceptable range for the constraints of the project, then they should be handled by exception since they are not expected to happen. Trap errors you expect, except when you do not expect.

Comment: " I think trapping those expected "exceptions" is the better choice here." - why? They're all still exceptional events and throwing an exception provides rich detailed information about the failure. It's like an error code+. There's no reason to dumb it down as a return code and loose all the detailed information about the failure. Plus if you consider the existing .NET framework implementation it throws exceptions when there are connection problems.

Comment: The other argument around exceptions is debugging - it's infuriating to tell it to break on exceptions and someone used it for flow control so it breaks continually before you ever get to the code you want to debug.  You can no longer tell what's good or bad.

Comment: You can filter your exceptions to only break on the one's you're interested in. And if you were trying to debug connections issues setting a break on a some sort of ConnectionFailedException is easier than searching all the places in the code where you make a call to Connect and try and set a breakpoint filter checking the return code.

Comment: yes you can filter unless it's a fairly generic exception type - then you're not breaking on real error conditions because someone chose to use it as flow control.  also, if you've ever debugged an app where someone has abused exceptions, you'll spend most of your time setting up your filters only to not break on real issues ...

Comment: Why? because if they are expected, they are NOT exceptional! When you expect a user to enter an invalid date, you trap it. When you expect your user to enter a non-zero for a denominator, it is an exception that they do not. Please correct me if I am not understanding the scope of the inputs vs. exception relationship here.

Comment: "because if they are expected, they are NOT exceptional! " - an expected behavior does not mean it's unexceptional. It's a matter of _frequency_ not _if_ it can happen.

Comment: So the biggest problem I think it revolves around Connect when the object is already connected. This is actually a programming error but if I throw an exception I have to check if the device is connected inside the method and outside it (to avoid exceptions!). If I ignore everything if the device is connected, I can check this only inside the method. Isn't better to use the second approach so?

Comment: That depends on whether attempting to connect when already connected is really a logic error. If there's no reason to fail, then just detect you're already connected and return early. No need to throw an exception. If it is an exception, you don't need to check inside your method, just let the exception propagate to the caller. The only reason you'd catch an exception in your method is if you are going to create your own custom exception to add details to the failure report. If the original exception is clear enough, just let it propagate up.

Comment: Good answer and comments, Paul. The *reductio ad absurdem* of the anti-exception police is that if you followed their advice you could never use them at all. The other issue I have with them is that exceptions *are* a form of flow control. The *original* intent of that saying was to stop people using them as goto's within a method, and believe me I've seen it. Like many other programming prescriptions, it has degenerated into a mindless dogma, now relying on an arbitrary redefinition of 'exceptional' so as to exclude all the useful cases. It's basically just a circular argument.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions should be exceptional and should not be used for flow control.

Depending on your app, if the connection already exists, you could choose to be passive an return successfully.

If there's incorrect settings, that's exceptional and should throw an exception.

Concerning the interop and connect, if you return bool, you have to ask yourself if consumers will have to handle and act differently based on the different error cases.  There's two models - if you return bool, you may need to return other info (as out) if consumers need to handle cases differently.  Handling error conditions should also not be based on string messages - you need some structured data like an exception type or error code.

On the Update call ...

If connection does't exist, you should throw an invalidOperationException since that's a programming error.

On connection post and interop errors, it goes back to the two patterns I discussed above.  If consumers need to handle different error cases you can either return bool with other info or throw.

Personally, I prefer to have less exceptions thrown and limit them to programming errors or truly exceptional cases.  For example, if you save an entity that violate a business rule is that an exception?  You could argue that but I would argue that it's not exceptional for someone to fill out a form and enter something that doesn't meet the rules in code - that's not exceptional.

A good rule of thumb is I like to attach a debugger with break on exception and under normal use, nothing should be thrown.  It should run clean.

Here's another SO post on exceptions:

[Trying to understand exceptions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238402/trying-to-understand-exceptions-in-c/7238519#7238519)

Comment: Your link is really interesting, I found it useful (I never thought about the situation on **when** I should catch)

Answer (score 0):

if your Connect/Update methods can fail, then by all means return a bool for failure/success.  you can also add an error code and/or error message methods/properties to your class that the programmer can access if he/she needs to.