# throw new vs try/catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is there a rule of thumb for handling exceptions wrt whether they should be handled in the same method of the exception-raising code or the caller?

In relation to this, what is the rule of thumb/general practise for deciding when to use "throw new" or catch blocks?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for exception management in Java or C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409563/best-practices-for-exception-management-in-java-or-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch means you can handle the exception.

You should catch exceptions when you can handle the condition and do something useful. Otherwise you should let it bubble up the call stack and perhaps someone above you can handle it. Some apps have unhandled exception handlers to handle it at the outer most layer but in general, unless you know you have some useful way to handle it, let it go.

throw new means you're creating an error condition that someone above you may want to catch.  Remember that the callers may want to handle/catch your error so do not throw new "Exception" or "ApplicationException" - throw a specific exception type that inherits from exception so the user knows what they're handling.

Last but not least, ensure exceptions are exceptional.  Do not throw unless it's an exceptional error case.  For example, code that checks if something exists should not throw and catch - it causes the debugger to break and it's expensive if called frequently.  On our team, we always look for code to run clean if no error case was encountered.

Here's a related post:
[Trying to understand exceptions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238402/trying-to-understand-exceptions-in-c-sharp/7238519#7238519)

Comment: What would be an example of a case where I catch an exception in the same method as it is called? throw new sounds like it should be used when a business rule (which is important to the stability of the program) is violated.

Comment: That's correct.  The simplest example would be argument validation (throw new ArgumentException).  Other examples could be rule violation.  The last draws opinions and varies - for example, is saving an entity with a missing field 'exceptional'?  Some (including me) could argue that users do it routinely and it's not exceptional - could return bool with out reason.  Or could have delegate callback for folks to handle business rule violations.

Answer (score 2):

Handling should be done on the lowest level that can handle the exception. E.g. if a low level arithmetic function gives a division by zero exception you can maybe continue. If a file I/O error occurs, maybe it should be handled very high in the flow of the application, it depends.

Throw new should be used where you want to throw an exception, so at the location where the exception occurs.

Catch blocks should be added where exceptions can be handled, and as written above, it depends where you want to catch them, preferably as soon as possible but high enough to be able to handle them.

Comment: the key to that statement is "that can handle the exception".  it's likely that deep in a common library, you do not know how to handle it - only the caller has context on how to handle that condition.

Comment: lower level/common libraries should often let the error bubble and let the consumer decide how to handle.  Perhaps they want to wait and retry etc...

Comment: Exactly, if the method can handle the exception itself which it has thrown, it is probably not an exception but a normal execution path (e.g. exiting a loop). One should always ask him/herself if an exception is REALLY an exception or if it occurs during every execution of the application.

Comment: Also watch out for showing dialogs in common libraries when an exception occurs, maybe you want to use it one day for a non-GUI application.